# Querying multiple indexes not working if one condition fails in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am trying to search for a key word on all the indexes. I have in my graph database.

Below is the query:

```
start n=node:Users(Name="Hello"), 
m=node:Location(LocationName="Hello")
return n,m
```

I am getting the nodes and if keyword "Hello" is present in both the indexes (Users and Location), and I do not get any results if keyword `Hello` is not present in any one of index.

Could you please let me know how to modify this **cypher query** so that I get results if "Hello" is present in any of the index keys (Name or LocationName).

Comment: Having a little trouble interpreting, could you post some example input/output? Are you just looking for the `OR` operator?

Comment: suppose I have two type nodes i.e User and Location.

Comment: suppose I have two types of nodes i.e User and Location. I have created two indexes on these nodes i.e Users (Key is Name) and Location(Key is LocationName). Now I want to do wild card search on these indexes. The word is "Hello".If suppose Hello keyword is present in Index  Users(key "Name) and not in Index Location( Key "LocationName") then the query is not returning any node though it should return all "n" nodes.

Comment: Can anyone please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

In 2.0 you can use UNION and have two separate queries like so:

```
start n=node:Users(Name="Hello")
return n
UNION
start n=node:Location(LocationName="Hello")
return n;
```

The problem with the way you have the query written is the way it calculates a cartesian product of pairs between `n` and `m`, so if `n` or `m` aren't found, no results are found. If one `n` is found, and two `m`s are found, then you get 2 results (with a repeating `n`). Similar to how the FROM clause works in SQL. If you have an empty table called `empty`, and you do `select * from x, empty;` then you'll get 0 results, unless you do an outer join of some sort.

Unfortunately, it's somewhat difficult to do this in 1.9. I've tried many iterations of things like `WITH collect(n) as n`, etc., but it boils down to the cartesian product thing at some point, no matter what.